# QGIS raster layer invalid

Tags: qgis, raster, qt, qgsmapcanvas

I am trying to load a georeferenced .tiff file into the map canvas in a Qt application. While it is displayed when the application is running on my laptop, the same image does not get loaded into the canvas when the application is running on another laptop. The error message says that the layer is invalid. I have tried to add every dll and lib file that I was using on my laptop but the problem persists. What could I be missing?